# Implementation of Chazelle's triangulation algorithm

Tags: algorithm, computational-geometry, chazelle-algorithm

There is an [algorithm for triangulating a polygon in linear time](https://www.cs.princeton.edu/~chazelle/pubs/polygon-triang.pdf) due to Chazelle (1991), but, AFAIK, there aren't any standard implementations of his algorithm in general mathematical software libraries.

Does anyone know of such an implementation?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4771736/powerful-algorithms-too-complex-to-implement/4771765#4771765) to the question [*Powerful algorithms too complex to implement*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4771736/3924118):

> According to Skiena (author of The Algorithm Design Manual), "[the] algorithm is quite hopeless to implement."

I've looked for an implementation before, but couldn't find one.  I think it's safe to assume no-one has implemented it due to its complexity, and I think it also has quite a large constant factor so wouldn't do well against `O(n lg n)` algorithms that have smaller constant factors.

Answer (score 2):

This is claimed to be an
[Implementation of Chazelle's Algorithm for Triangulating a Simple Polygon in Linear Time](https://github.com/FashGek/chazelle-triangulation) (mainly C++ and C).